# Google Protobuff compiling

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to make my Web API work with Google Protobuff and I tried to follow the instructions in Github but I cannot find the way how to compile protobuff file so it will create c# files for my project. Can someone please tell me instructions in order to do that.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "protobuff file" you mean a .proto file, the tool you're looking for is `protoc`, and it [ships in the release](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases).

Alternatively, both `protoc` and `protogen` are available for online usage at https://protogen.marcgravell.com - `protogen` is protobuf-net's equivalent tooling, for an independent re-implementation.

There may also be MSBuild/CLI tools available separately via a protobuf nuget package, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, on documentation  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial it says run the compiler I am not able to find the compiler in that downloaded file.

Comment: @Kakos649 like I said: it *ships in the release* (that I linked to); pick, for example, [protoc-3.6.0-win32.zip](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-win32.zip) - this has a `/bin/protoc.exe`

Comment: @Kakos649 it [*really is there*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RClpX.png) - if you can't find it, check your anti-virus isn't deleting it